# get all values based on repeated id(s) - mysql

Tags: mysql

Thanks for your help i'm stuck on this problem.
Let me explain it, i have this kind of table, Table1 and Table2.

Table1

```
-------|
id     |
-------|
100    | 
101    | 
102    | 
103    | 
104    | 
105    |
```

---

Table2

```
-------|---------|
id     |value    |
-------|---------|
100    |  A      |
100    |  B      |
100    |  C      |
101    |  D      |
105    |  E      |
105    |  F      |
```

and

Desired result :

```
-------|---------
id     |value    
-------|---------
100    |  A   B   C    
101    |  D 
102    |
103    |
104    |
105    |  E   F
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: @Barmar - That deserves to be an answer

Comment: @EdHeal It's more of a hint to how he can do it himself. I don't think this deserves a real answer.

Comment: @Barmar - I beg to differ - but you get a +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.id, 
GROUP_CONCAT(table2.value ORDER BY value ASC SEPARATOR ' ') value
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

The result will be like this:

```
 id     value
--------------
100     A B C
101     D
102     NULL
103     NULL
104     NULL
105     E F
```

If yo want remove NULL value

```
SELECT 
  table1.id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    COALESCE(table2.value, '') 
    ORDER BY VALUE ASC SEPARATOR ' '
  ) VALUE 
FROM
  table1 
  LEFT JOIN table2 
    ON table2.id = table1.id 
GROUP BY table1.id
```

final result:

```
 id     value
--------------
100     A B C
101     D
102     
103     
104     
105     E F
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using the `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT table2.id, GROUP_CONCAT(table2.value ORDER BY value ASC SEPARATOR ' ') value
FROM table2 
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.id = table2.id
GROUP BY table1.id
```

Comment: But it return only 3 rows 100,101 and 105

Comment: @SanchuabaciesAba - No it doesn't it should return all rows.